# How to explore the request/response details in collection run

Tags: postman

When I run a collection how can explore each request/response details? I don't see any possibility to do that on UI:

[image]

[This page](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/running_collections) says:

> You can get a more detailed per iteration view of the results by
>   clicking the ‘>’ arrow when you hover over a request.

But I don't really understand what I should hover over.

Comment: which version of postman do you have ? you may update it as, in the latest version, I can see test step details thanks to the arrow (up/down arrow, though) at the right side of the window ...

Comment: thanks, no longer use it